# Unable to connect to postgres using deno.js

Tags: postgresql, deno

Unable to connect to postgres in deno.js.

Here is the configuration:

```
const dbCreds = {
      applicationName: "appname",
      user: "user_sfhjwre",
      database: "d9iu8mve7nen",
      password: "68790f31eelkhlashdlkagsvADSDa52f9d8faed894c037ef6f9c9f09885603",
      hostname: "ec2-345-34-97-212.eu-east-1.xx.amazonaws.com",
      port: 5432,
    };
    export { dbCreds };
```

Usage:

```
import { Client } from "https://deno.land/x/postgres/mod.ts";        
import { dbCreds } from "../config.ts";

const client = new Client(dbCreds);    
await client.connect();
```

Also tried:

```
config = "postgres://user@localhost:5432/test?application_name=my_custom_app";
const client = new Client(config);
await client.connect();
```

Same result:

```
Uncaught Error: Unknown auth message code 1397113172
```

Is there anything wrong with the syntax, I can connect to the same db using prisma.

Comment: What does the Postgres log show when you get the error? Where is Client coming from?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver There are no logs on Heroku for failed connections.

Comment: So what does: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors show? Also where is Client coming from?

Comment: As mentioned in question, it is a deno.js client throwing error mentioned in question again. I do't think it is getting to Heroku. There is nothing in logs. @AdrianKlaver

Comment: In particular this:https://deno.land/x/pg I'm guessing. Does the Postgres server require SSL and do you need ```certFile: 'some_cert'```? And you know dbCreds is coming over correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's the client. Don't need certFile, I'm connecting to db without it from prisma client. I'm  sure configuration is correct because it throws the same error in both cases. @AdrianKlaver

Comment: Well I'm not seeing where the URI form is allowed so I would expect an error. Don't know where to go from here. You might want to file issue here: https://github.com/deno-library/pg/issues.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the PostgreSQL server in a remote server and, each time my public IP changes, I need to change the pg_hba.conf in order to set my new public IP as authorized for remote access.

Hope this helps.

Best regards.

Comment: It should allow you to connect without ssl(pg_hba.conf).

Comment: Yes, I connect without SSL.